# Make subclass inherit existing instance of base class

Tags: php, c++, oop, inheritance

I am trying to rewrite an application from C++ to PHP and I'm curious how I can initialize my subclass with values from an existing instance of my base class. The reason for this is that I have a list of base classes and each base class can have multiple configurations. I implemented this in C++ by calling the copy constructor for the base class from the initializer in the subclass:

```
class A {
public:
    A(int a) : a(a) {};
protected:
    int a;
}

class B : public A {
public:
    B(int b, const A &a) : A(a), b(b) {};
private:
    int b;
}
```

I've been trying to figure out how to implement something similar in PHP, but my knowledge of the PHP object model doesn't reflect any similar functionality to what I described above.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this and change what is not needed.

```
<?php

class A
{
    protected $a;
    function __construct($_a)
    {
        $this->a = $_a;
    }

    function PrintA()
    {
        echo $this->a;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    private $b;

    function __construct($_b, $_a)
    {
        $this->b = $_b;
        parent::__construct($_a);
    }

    function PrintB()
    {
        echo $this->b;
    }
}

$classA = new A(5);
$classA->printA();

$classB = new B(5,2);
$classB->printA();

?>
```

Comment: I know you can implement it this way by manually setting all of the values from A in B, however, my actual implementation has about 20 variables and manually retyping those heavily violates DRY methodology and sits wrong with me.

Comment: you can use the parent::__construct($variable). Don't rly understand what you are trying to do

Comment: also what makes even less sense is your second parameter in class B which is a reference to class A and then you call the class A constructor and send it as a int.